# How to pass variable that has been altered with prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

How can one pass a variable with prepareForSegue that has been altered since it's instantiation? When I attempt to pass a variable with prepareForSegue it sends the value it is instantiated with, not the value I have altered it to.

Code:

```
var friendChosen:String!

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "toChat") {
        let theVC: chatViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! chatViewController
        theVC.friendChosen = friendChosen
    }
}
```

When the user clicks on a button, the friendChosen variable should take the value of a name. It does, and successfully prints it's value to the terminal, however it does not seem to register when the segue is called (after it has been changed).

```
func chooseFriend(sender: UIButton) {
    let requestIndex = sender.tag
    self.friendChosen = self.friends.objectAtIndex(requestIndex) as! String
}
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Added the answers to my original question

Comment: Does your view controller remain visible all the time between the calls of `chooseFriend` and `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: the chooseFriend UIButton is a segue to the view controller that I am attempting to pass the variable to. Does this help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the `chooseFriend` `UIButton` is a segue to the view controller that I am attempting to pass the variable to.

Since the segue is triggered by `UIButton`, the call of `prepareForSegue` happens *before* the call of `UIButton`'s action, i.e. `chooseFriend`. The `chooseFriend` variable has not been set yet, so `prepareForSegue` sees an empty value.

You can fix this by combining the two methods into one: cast the sender to `UIButton`, take its `tag`, and set the variable, like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, senderObj: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "toChat") {
        let sender = senderObj as! UIButton
        let requestIndex = sender.tag
        let theVC: chatViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! chatViewController
        theVC.friendChosen = self.friends.objectAtIndex(requestIndex) as! String
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!